# Is there a way to make a price rise with more purchased items?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to have one of my buttons hire miners to work for the player, however I want the price to hire the workers to increase in price with every purchase. So the first purchase will cost $250, but the subsequent purchases I want to increase by say 35%.

Here's the important code block:

```
$(function() { /* The hire miner function */
$('#hireminer').click(function(){
    hireMiner();
});

function hireMiner() {
var minerct = parseInt($("#minerct").text()); /* minerct is miner count */
var money = parseInt($("#Money").text());
if(money >= 250) {
    minerct = isNaN(minerct) ? 0 : minerct + 1;
    money = isNaN(money) ? 0 : money - 250;
}
    $("#minerct").text(minerct);
    $("#Money").text(money);

    function resetCounter() {
        $("#minerct").text(0);
        $("#Money").text(0);
    }
};
});
```

Currently I have it cost 250 each time but I am unsure how to make the price increase by 35%.

Comment: You can store the "current price" somewhere on the page or on the server...consider jQuery "data", an HTML hidden input, the innerHTML of a hidden div, or an ajax call to update the new price on the server

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob That is probably an amazing answer, but I honestly don't know what to do with that information. I have never worked with that before so I would still be severely lost

Answer (score 2):

```
var price = 250;
$(function() { /* The hire miner function */
    $('#hireminer').click(function(){
    hireMiner();
});

function hireMiner() {
    var minerct = parseInt($("#minerct").text()); /* minerct is miner count */
    var money = parseInt($("#Money").text());
    if(money >= price) {
        minerct = isNaN(minerct) ? 0 : minerct + 1;
        money = isNaN(money) ? 0 : money - price;
        price += price * .35;
    }
    $("#minerct").text(minerct);
    $("#Money").text(money);

    function resetCounter() {
        $("#minerct").text(0);
        $("#Money").text(0);
    }
};
```